# infinite inner product space

Tags: inner-products

I am trying to teach myself about ***infinite*** inner product spaces.

In the article "Orthonormal basis" in Wikipedia it reads

> In functional analysis, the concept of an orthonormal basis can be generalized to arbitrary (infinite-dimensional) inner product spaces. Given a pre-Hilbert space H, an orthonormal basis for H is an orthonormal set of vectors with the property that every vector in H can be written as an infinite linear combination of the vectors in the basis. In this case, the orthonormal basis is sometimes called a Hilbert basis for H. Note that an orthonormal basis in this sense is not generally a Hamel basis, since infinite linear combinations are required. Specifically, the linear span of the basis must be dense in H, but it may not be the entire space.
>
> If we go on to Hilbert spaces, a non-orthonormal set of vectors having the same linear span as an orthonormal basis may not be a basis at all. For instance, any square-integrable function on the interval [−1, 1] can be expressed (almost everywhere) as an infinite sum of Legendre polynomials (an orthonomal basis), but not necessarily as an infinite sum of the monomials x^n.

Because I am new to all this I struggle to understand what it actually means and why that last example is true.

In the article "inner product space" under "Orthonormal sequences" the first six lines or so (up to "E is dense in V") remain a bit of a mystery to me, too.

[Orthonormal sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Orthonormal_sequences)

Any insight to these slightly cryptic to me statements is appreciated.

Comment: I know that you’re studying $\textbf{infinite}$ inner product spaces, but most of the statements mean the same thing as in finite dimensional vector spaces. Which statements are confusing? As for why the monomials are not a basis, I thought they were (or still think they are), just not an orthonormal basis, and that the Legendre polynomials are just Gram-Schmidt applied to that basis to make an orghonormal basis. So I don’t know why a square integrable function can be written as the infinite sum of Legendre polynomials, but not necessarily as the infinite sum of monomials.

Comment: @Joe I think it goes deeper than that. I have two different procecess in mind: one is to add more terms to a sum **without** changing the previous terms, and the other is **with** changing the previous terms. Are these processes crucial in understanding the example about polynomials? That I would like to know.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean about those two processes. I think about the Legendre polynomials as orthonormal basis vectors, just like $\hat{i}, \hat{j}, \hat{k} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. There is technically a difference between an orthonormal basis for an infinite Hilbert space, which allows countable sums of vectors, versus a Hamel basis, for which every vector can be represented by a finite linear combination. But I find most of the concepts analogous to finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: I’m surprised no one has answered this yet. I encourage you to ask more questions, as you have them, if you cannot find the information yourself. You’ll probably get the best response rate when you ask very specific questions.